# HTML/Javascript: Tracking-callback to external site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsonp

I need to find a way to notify a 3rd party website about an user action on my website. A server sided connection is not desired. Hashing with private keys is used to sign the request so users can't abuse it.

My question is how I can send this request safely.

- tracking image: XSA possible
- iframe: XSA, frame breaker
- script include: evilness at its best
- JSONP (with jQuery): ??
- others?

Does someone know if it's possible to inject Javascript in JSONP answers? I mean to bypass browser boundaries JSONP is Javascript that calls a function with the JSON as parameter but it could also contain other javascript calls. Does jQuery somehow check if there is malicious content in jsonp callbacks?

Comment: Take a look at RPC http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call

Comment: If you don't trust the 3rd party, you should not use JSONP. It is just a script include with an agreed-upon callback.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to target modern browsers, and you control all the domains, you can create an HTTP access control policy to allow them to communicate with each other. However, since that doesn't appear to be the case, you're going to be stuck with JSONP.

It's funny that you mention "script include" as "evilness at its best", because that's exactly what JSONP is. Since, until recently, browsers were incapable of cross-domain requests, the only way to get anything from a 3rd-party client-side was to include a script from that 3rd party. JSONP simply takes advantage of this workaround returning the JSON inside of a function definition, which your script can then call to get the included data.

Comment: Yeah that was kinda what my question is about. If JSONP is "parsed" like jQuery can parse JSON or if it's just a simple script include. To bypass boundaries JSONP must be direct script include, doesn't it? So everything in there will be executed not just the jsonp callback function. Edit: And no, I don't controll the domains. I guess a <img> tracking will be best. XSA is still a problem but it exists on many pages.

Comment: Not quite. JSONP is a very specific format: a JSON response wrapped by a callback function. You're only going to be able to get away with that very limited bit of JavaScript. It's not a generalized response to put whatever JS code you like in.